# How do I get the report grouping to look at the whole number rather than the first two digits?

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have grouped everything by diameter but when I run the report it's only looking at the first two digits of the number, so groups them like:

```
10
101
104
11
112
116
12
```

I don't know how to get it to look at all 3 digits rather than the first 2.

Comment: Well Grouping shall work for complete number and not just 2.
Could you please edit your question and update few screenshots. This might give more Idea where exactly is failing.
Also where do you see issue with the result you get.
Every Number is unique and hence group and shown once

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that your issue stems from the datatype of the field you are grouping by.  If the field is a `VARCHAR`, it will group as your report is currently grouping.  If the field is a `NUMERIC` datatype, it will group by the full number.  Check your query and verify that the field is providing the correct datatype and you should have a working grouping.